# Angular 4 - router.url unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How do I mock router.url in angular 4 unit testing?

I use router.url in ngOnint in my component but in my test the value for router.url is '/'

Comment: can you provide more details what are trying to do , from description it is not very clear what exactly you want to do.

Comment: show Your codes

Answer (score 19):

In Angular v9 `Router.url` is a readonly getter property. You can force the private property value to set the url property:

```
    const mockUrlTree = router.parseUrl('/heroes/captain-marvel');
    // @ts-ignore: force this private property value for testing.
    router.currentUrlTree = mockUrlTree;
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, when both, RouterTestingModule and router.url are used in unit tests

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes if you are using a later version of Angular then the other answers will not work.

Comment: Not possible anymore in Angular 17, currentUrlTree is readonly as well.

Comment: The problem isn't that `currentUrlTree` is readonly. The problem is it is now also a getter. The raw value is now [buried](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b87324d8f07714a1d24d0dc3e9bef5e676041db3/packages/router/src/statemanager/state_manager.ts#L92) in another Service that isn't end user accessible

Answer (score 3):

you could use jasmine spyObj. 
In you `TestBed`:

```
providers:[
 {
 provide: Router,
 usevalue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Router',['methodOne','methodTwo]),
 },
],
```

in beforeEach:

```
router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);
```

in the test:

```
it('should...', ()=> {
 (router.methodOne as Spy).and.returnValue(whateverValue)// if you wanna mock the response
});
```

Comment: If it needs further explaining, please let me know :)

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like a solution 
[jasmine angular 4 unit test router.url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314181/jasmine-angular-4-unit-test-router-url)

```
const router = TestBed.get(Router);
router.url = '/path/to/anything';
// now you can run your tested method:
component.ngOnint();
```

Comment: I am getting an error `cannot assign to 'url' bacause its a constant property`