# jasmine angular 4 unit test router.url

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, router

I am unit testing a function in angular 4 project using jasmine which a switch  statement like mentioned below:

```
    switch(this.router.url) {

    case 'firstpath': {
               // some code
            }
        break;
    case 'secondpath': {
               // some more code
            }
       break;
    default:
        break;

    }
```

In my spec.ts file. I can't stub or change the value of router.url.I want my cases to execute but default is executing. I tried different ways to set or spyOn and return value, but everytime url is '/'. Every suggestion or solution will be welcomed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First you need to mock router in your testing module:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
       provide: Router,
       useValue: {
          url: '/path'
       } // you could use also jasmine.createSpyObj() for methods
    } 
  ]
});
```

You can also change the url in the test and run your tested method:

```
const router = TestBed.inject(Router);
// @ts-ignore: force this private property value for testing.
router.url = '/path/to/anything';
// now you can run your tested method:
component.testedFunction();
```

As you mention `spyOn` doesnt work because it works only for methods/functions. But `url` is a property.

Comment: @martin you are my savior!

I tried  using `spyOnProperty(spyRouter, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('test');`
 But it did not workout quiet so well.

Comment: I'm getting an error "TypeError: Cannot set property url of [object Object] which has only a getter" when using router.url = '/path/to/anything'

Comment: TestBed should return `any` type so you shouldn't get this error. Maybe you do `const router: Router = TestBed.get(Router);` instead?

Comment: If you're getting the error that is in Christoper Grigg's comment the router may not be mocked our properly. You can try the `spyOnProperty` and use it as `spyOnProperty(router, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('yourUrl')`

Comment: can we do similar thing using `RouterTestingModule` ?

Comment: @MartinNuc,really thanks for your answer.It also solved my router juni test problem.

Comment: `TestBed.get` is deprecated by `TestBed.Inject`. Unfortunately, the URL becomes get only when switching to `.Inject`.

Comment: @Peter You could probably always fall back to any: `(router as any).url = '/path/to/anything';

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect on read-only property when using `TestBed.inject` on newer Angular versions.

Answer (score 8):

For people using Angular 9 and above property url is now a readonly property and so *spyOnProperty* will not work. It's also confusing as you won't get an error, but you won't see any "spying" either.

To solve this, use the following code:

```
const mockUrlTree = routerSpy.parseUrl('/mynewpath/myattribute');
// @ts-ignore: force this private property value for testing.
routerSpy.currentUrlTree = mockUrlTree;
```

Thanks to Rob on this post here for the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63623284/1774291

Comment: Not possible anymore in Angular 17, currentUrlTree is readonly as well.