# How to set current route in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-router

When unit testing a component that depends on being on a certain route, how do I set the current URL?

**component.html**

```html
<button class="menu-button" *ngIf="router.url === '/home'">
```

**component.spec.ts**

```js
it('menu button should toggle side navs', () => {
  const buttonEl = toolbarElement.querySelector('.menu-button');

  (buttonEl as HTMLElement).click();
  expect(navigationServiceSpy.sideNavLeftToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

`buttonEl` is **undefined** because I cannot set the current route of the component.
I have tried the following without luck:

- navigating to the URL in the unit test using router.navigate(['/home']) on the 'real' router
- spying on the router and navigating to the URL

In both cases `router.url` remains undefined and I cannot get my conditional element to render :(

Comment: Please share your test, the component code and the test-setup code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jasmine angular 4 unit test router.url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314181/jasmine-angular-4-unit-test-router-url)